# Airflow scheduler container does not start after config update

Tags: containers, airflow

I have exec into scheduler container and change /opt/bitnami/airflow/airflow.cfg on the API line to

[api]
auth_backend=airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth

When i try to restart the container, it exited.

I use docker start -i airflow-scheduler, the below returns

```
Welcome to the Bitnami airflow-scheduler container
Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-airflow-scheduler
Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-airflow-scheduler/issues

INFO  ==> Starting airflow-scheduler...
Waiting for db...
Database is ready
INFO  ==> Starting airflow...
[2023-01-03 08:26:02,692] {__init__.py:71} CRITICAL - Cannot import Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/__init__.py", line 55, in load_auth
airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth for API authentication due to: No module named 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    api_auth = import_module(auth_backend)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/bin/airflow", line 26, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 93, in <module>
    api.load_auth()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/__init__.py", line 73, in load_auth
    raise AirflowException(err)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: No module named 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
```

and the container exits. Could someone help me on how to change back the auth.backend to deny_all

Thanks

All are stated as above

Comment: which version of airflow you are using?

Comment: the version is v1.10.11. Thanks Hussein